# Gráfico de Regressão no R ou Python

Tags: python, r, regressão

É possível reproduzir esse gráfico de Regressão no R ou Python?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Obs**. Esse gráfico foi produzido usando o objeto QAQC do acQuire 4. [Link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/use-regression-lines-paired-data-scatter-plots-quality-paul-fell/)

E esse é o modelo que que criei até o momento.

```
dados = read.csv("C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\data3.csv", header = T)

# 0. Build linear model 
model <- lm(CK ~ OR, data = dados)
summary(model)

# 1. Add predictions 
pred.int <- predict(model, interval = "prediction")
mydata <- cbind(dados, pred.int)


# 2. Regression line
library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(OR, CK)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = lm)


# 3. Add prediction intervals
p + geom_line(aes(y = lwr), color = "red", linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_line(aes(y = upr), color = "red", linetype = "dashed")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha base de dados: [Link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkUK-qGIRBnMgblFmmGPhK4v_LNanw?e=gXcYy2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As linhas no gráfico que quer reproduzir não correspondem ao resultado de uma regressão linear, mas simplesmente à porcentagens do valor de *x*. Pode adicioná-las com `stat_function`. Se for usar em vários gráficos, pode primeiro guardá-las em uma lista.

Estou usando dados simulados para facilitar a  reprodução por outros usuários:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(89)
mydata <- data.frame(OR = sort(rnorm(20, 10, 4)), CK = sort(rnorm(20, 12, 5)))


linhas_ref <- list(stat_function(fun = function(x) x, size= 1.1, linetype = "dashed"),
                   stat_function(fun = function(x) 0.9*x, linetype = "dashed", colour = "gray40"),
                   stat_function(fun = function(x) 1.1*x, linetype = "dashed", colour = "gray40"),
                   stat_function(fun = function(x) 0.8*x, colour = "red"),
                   stat_function(fun = function(x) 1.2*x, colour = "red"))

ggplot(mydata, aes(OR, CK)) +
  linhas_ref +
  geom_point(colour = "blue") +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se preferir que os eixos não iniciem no 0, ao invés focando na região em que aparecem os dados, pode usar `geom_abline` no lugar de `geom_function`:

```
geom_abline(slope = .8, intercept = 0, colour = "red") + ...
```

Comment: Consegui resolver de outra maneira, de todo modo obrigado pelo apoio.

Answer (score 0):

Solução que utilizei para resolver.

```
dataset$ï..QAQC_STATUS = as.factor(dataset$ï..QAQC_STATUS)


library("ggplot2")

p <- ggplot(dataset, aes(ASSAYVALUE_OR, ASSAYVALUE_CK, color=(ï..QAQC_STATUS))) +
     geom_point(size=0.9) +
     geom_line(mapping=aes(x = ASSAYVALUE_CK, y = ASSAYVALUE_CK*1.2, color = "20% Diference"), linetype = "solid", size = 0.6) +
     geom_line(mapping=aes(x = ASSAYVALUE_CK, y = ASSAYVALUE_CK*1.1, color = "10% Diference"), linetype = "dashed", size = 0.6) +
     geom_line(mapping=aes(x = ASSAYVALUE_CK, y = ASSAYVALUE_CK, color = "X=Y"), linetype = "solid", size = 0.6) +
     geom_line(mapping=aes(x = ASSAYVALUE_CK*1.1, y = ASSAYVALUE_CK, color = "10% Diference"), linetype = "dashed", size = 0.6) +
     geom_line(mapping=aes(x = ASSAYVALUE_CK*1.2, y = ASSAYVALUE_CK, color = "20% Diference"), linetype = "solid", size = 0.6) +
     scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "brown4", 'black','darkslategrey'))+
     labs(color = 'Legend: ') +
     theme(legend.position="bottom") +
     labs(title = "Gráfico - 3") +
     theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
     
p
```

Comment: Usando `geom_line` você precisa gerar dados para serem plotados. Usando `geom_abline` ou `geom_function` isso não é necessário, o que permite que o código seja armazenado em uma lista e usado em qualquer *plot* com qualquer conjunto de dados.